# what is performance tuning in obiee & how we work on this what is the procedure? help me out with an example,Thank you

Tags: obiee

How we are going to work on Performance tuning in obiee?

Answer (score 0):

Performance tuning isn't something you do after a checklist. Especially not for a solution like OBIEE which is an analytical platform and therefor extremely dependent on good data performance.

Performance is something you manage and plan for from day 1, not at the end of a project.

There are documents on google which claim to be tuning guides or best practices list, but those are misleading since they are at best "correct in a certain kind of situation" and at worst something which will cause you even more problems when you start to randomly twist knobs without knowing the implications.

Comment: Hey! chris, Thank you & we use hints in rpd for increasing the performance of the reports in obiee right?

Comment: 1.) No, that's a hack. You design performance from the beginning.
2.) It's not "reports". It's "analyses". "Reports" are BI Publisher and that's a different technology.

I suggest you get a proper training on OBIEE. You can not build a valid system if you do not yet comprehend the basics.

Comment: am new to obiee as a fresher

Comment: If you need help on that, let me know.

Comment: yeah..chris,i have a question, my dashboard and analysis performance is poor,let me say trying to see data, it is taking around 10-15 min. time to open,Is there way to make this open quickly?

Comment: I meant the training ;-)